# How to write raw MIDI bytes to Linux Midi Through client?

Tags: debian, alsa, midi

The command line utility amidi may be used to send MIDI hexadecimal bytes to any alsa rawmidi port identified in `amidi -l`.
I have a piece of music software (Organteq) which monitors Midi Through for any messages. I would like to write to this software by writing to Midi Through.

Unfortunately, the port does not show up on amidi and thus I cannot write to it. The port does show up on aplaymidi and pmidi, both of which do not support raw bytes, only sending midi files:

```
aplaymidi -l
 Port    Client name                      Port name
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 20:0    CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3               CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA.
```

It is also visible on aconnect:

```
aconnect -l
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
    0 'Timer           '
        Connecting To: 144:0
    1 'Announce        '
        Connecting To: 144:0, 128:0
client 14: 'Midi Through' [type=kernel]
    0 'Midi Through Port-0'
        Connecting To: 128:1
client 20: 'CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3' [type=kernel,card=1]
    0 'CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA'
        Connecting To: 128:2
client 128: 'Organteq' [type=user,pid=2372]
    0 'announcements   '
        Connected From: 0:1
    1 'Midi Through Port-0'
        Connected From: 14:0
    2 'CLASSIC ORGAN CMK3 CLASSIC ORGA'
        Connected From: 20:0
client 144: 'PipeWire-System' [type=user,pid=1100]
    0 'input           '
        Connected From: 0:1, 0:0
client 145: 'PipeWire-RT-Event' [type=user,pid=1100]
    0 'input           '
```

So, how may I write 1) to client 14, or perhaps even better, 2) write directly to client 128?

Answer (score 3):

From my inquiries there is no command-line utility. However, using the ALSA C interface this is possible.
One must open the Linux ALSA sequencer using `snd_seq_open()`, and name the opened handle with `snd_seq_set_client_name`, then create a port using `snd_seq_create_simple_port()` with the designation `SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_READ | SND_SEQ_PORT_CAP_SUBS_READ` (to allow other ALSA clients to read from the port).

At this point your port should be visible using pmidi -l or aconnect -l while your program is running.

Then to write to your chosen ALSA port, simply create a `snd_seq_event_t` struct for your MIDI event and fill in the relevant information (whether by manually assigning fields or by using macro functions like below), and finally send with `snd_seq_event_output()`.

```
snd_seq_event_t ev;
int err;
snd_seq_ev_clear(&ev); snd_seq_ev_set_direct(&ev); //direct passing mode (i.e. no queue)

snd_seq_ev_set_dest(&ev, 128, 1); //id and port number of destination. could also subscribe to this port and then use snd_seq_ev_set_subs to send to subscribers
snd_seq_ev_set_noteon(&ev, 0, 45, 127);  //channel, key number, velocity
if ((err = snd_seq_event_output(seq_handle, &ev)) < 0) {
    printf("send to sequencer failed \n"); return -1; }
snd_seq_drain_output(seq_handle); //call when nothing further to send
```

Answer (score 2):

Load the snd-virmidi module (`modprobe snd-virmidi`). This creates a virtual sound card with several raw MIDI devices that you can also access from Organteq.